# AVURLAsset called API twice?

Tags: swift, avplayer, avurlasset

I'm trying to make a request to my server through `AVPlayer` with additional header parameters. The server returns an `.mp3` file and a record is inserted in the DB for history preview purposes. However, the DB record is doubled, with a time difference of less than 1s.

```
let headers: [String:String] = [
    "track_id" : "\(songid)",
    "type" : "\(songtype)",
    "user_id" : MyAccount.shared.id,
    "token" : MyAccount.shared.apiToken,
]

let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: AVURLAsset(url: MusicPlayer.url, options: [
    "AVURLAssetHTTPHeaderFieldsKey":headers
]))

// this is a queue player
player.insert(item, after: nil)
player.play()
```

Both iOS 9.2 and 10.3 show the same results.

Comment: They are in a custom music player class , not any view controller , and is triggered by user click

Comment: Have you looked at the requests that AVFoundation is making with a web proxy?

Comment: @Rhythmic no , I didnt. how can I look at the request?